# What does the new Operator and String do in this program?

Tags: java, string, char

I am beginner to Java, and I am reading up on Arrays from the tutorial at Oracle.

My question involves this code:

```
class ArrayCopyDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] copyFrom = { 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'e',
            'i', 'n', 'a', 't', 'e', 'd' };
        char[] copyTo = new char[7];

        System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 2, copyTo, 0, 7);
        System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
    }
}
```

Specifically,

```
 System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
```

What does new String(copyTo) exactly do, or rather why use new and String? What are they doing together? (I understand that they print out "caffein" but only in a very general sense.

Comment: It's a constructor call, like any other constructor call. Do you understand constructors in general? `String` is just the name of a class.

Comment: No, I don't think I've seen anything explaining constructors yet.

Comment: You should probably seek some tutorials on object-oriented programming then.

Comment: @Chase: Okay, it's probably worth getting hold of a book about Java, or reading up on constructors in the tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D%29) is your friend:

> **public String(char[] value)**
>
> Allocates a new String so that it
>   represents the sequence of characters currently contained in the
>   character array argument. The contents of the character array are
>   copied; subsequent modification of the character array does not affect
>   the newly created string.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> value - The initial value of the
>   string

Comment: I wish more people would link to documentation!

Answer (score 2):

> What does new String(copyTo) exactly do,

It creates a new String object. String class has an Constructor which accepts an char array, which converts the char Array into string literal.

[**new String(char[] arr) Source**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28char%5B%5D%29)

> Allocates a new String so that it represents the sequence of
>   characters currently contained in the character array argument. The
>   contents of the character array are copied; subsequent modification of
>   the character array does not affect the newly created string.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new `String` object containing the text defined by the `char` array you pass as a parameter. It's just another of the constructors defined in the `String` class, take a look at it:

```
public String(char value[]) {
    this.offset = 0;
    this.count = value.length;
    this.value = StringValue.from(value); //returns a copy of the char array
                                          //by using Array.copyOf
}
```

Aside from looking at the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D%29), diging into `String`'s code can help you to comprehend how does it work. `this.value` is the internal array used to allocate the `char`s that conform the `String`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `println` only accepts the type `String`. What you have is a `char` array.

The `new` keyword indicates that `String` is a constructor of the class `String` (as in construction of a new `String` object).

In the Android Developers site you have a list of all the constructors possible:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html

Specifically, the one you are using is:

```java
String(char[] data)
```